# SQL-Server - Where are Linked Servers in the Object Explorer in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server

I searched Stack Overflow but didn't find this question, putting it out there in case others may need it.

Where is Linked Servers in the Object Explorer in SQL Server Management Studio, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server Objects -> Linked Servers:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Linked Servers are located in Server Objects in the Object Explorer